# Tikz/Pgfplots - Can not plot trig functions with a horizontal shift

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot an acos graph using `tikz` and `pgfplots` where the function should receive `x-2` as an argument to plot the graph of `acos(2-x)` which gives the acos(x) function a h-shift to the right and a reflection on the y-axis

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    axis lines=center,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-1.0, xmax=1,
    ymin=-0.2 , ymax=180,
]

\addplot[name path=A, domain=-1:1, samples=101]{acos(2-x)};
```

However, I always get the following error when compiling:

```
Missing number treated as zero
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
```

Adding r at the end of the `2-x` does not help either.

Comment: I am compiling with Overleaf, by the way.

Comment: You are asking pgf to compute acos of 3... please adjust the domain such that the argument of acos is between -1 and 1.

Comment: Actually, I understood what you meant eventually...kinda. So after changing the domain from -1:1 to 3:[any number >3] it plots with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it asks pgf to compute `acos` of `3` and other values that are outside of its domain. Another problem is that you present only fragments. Here is a simple way to shift the graph to the right and reflect it at the vertical axis: instead of `\addplot <function(x)>;` use `\addplot (<hshift-x,{function(x)});`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    axis lines=center,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-0.2 , ymax=180,
]
\addplot[dashed, domain=-1:1, samples=101] {acos(x)};
\addplot[name path=A, domain=-1:1, samples=101] (2-x,{acos(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The dashed curve is just the untransformed `acos` function to show that this work.